# Apply VR lens distortion (barrel distortion) to live video feed

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing, virtual-reality

I am trying to create a custom VR headset that displays a live feed from a remote camera, and in order for the view to be clear from the vr headset, I need to duplicate the image from the camera for both eyes and apply barrel distortion (see attached picture) to them to offset the distortion from the lenses. Duplicating the image should be simple, but I do not know how to apply the distortion.

Most of the solutions I've found online are built in to some sort of game engine or VR SDK, but I don't want to use a game engine since I'm only processing a raw camera feed.

I am planning on using OpenCV to do this and I'm hoping to get at least 30fps at 1080p (hardware is an NVIDIA Jetson Nano with a CSI camera). What would be the best way to go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: I'm very interested in your question, did you ended up with a solution?